# Android MySQLite problems when compiling

Tags: android, sqlite

Im progressing with creating a simple database for a project at school, however the code itself shows no errors, but when i run the project in an emulator, it spits out an error. 
I Think the problem is stemming from the AlertDialog, but im not sure whats wrong with the syntax
Here is a copy of my code..

```
package com.example.bash1.sqlitediss;

import android.app.AlertDialog; 
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar; 
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelper myDb;
private Button button3;
Button buttonviewall;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    buttonviewall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    viewAll();

}
{

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DatabaseActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    });
    {
    }

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

public void viewAll() {
    buttonviewall.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
                    if (res.getCount() == 0)
                    // show message
                    {
                        showMessage("Error", "Nothing found");
                        return;
                    }

                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    while (res.moveToNext()) {
                        buffer.append("ID :" + res.getString(0) + "\n");
                        buffer.append("Name :" + res.getString(1) + "\n");
                        buffer.append("Datereceived :" + res.getString(2) + "\n");
                        buffer.append("Expirydate :" + res.getString(3) + "\n\n");
                    }
                    // Show all data
                    showMessage("Data", buffer.toString());

                }
            }

    );
}


public void showMessage(String title, String Message) {
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      builder.setCancelable(true);
      builder.setTitle(title);
      builder.setMessage(Message);
      builder.show();

    builder.show();
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Activitymain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Error message log:

```
04-20 06:40:57.114 17890-17890/com.example.bash1.sqlitediss E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.example.bash1.sqlitediss, PID: 17890
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bash1.sqlitediss/com.example.bash1.sqlitediss.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:68)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:145)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:28)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:41)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:188)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:170)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:502)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:174)
                                                                              at com.example.bash1.sqlitediss.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:35)
                                                                              at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: add all the activities in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Can you tell what `DatabaseActivity` extends ?

Comment: The DatabaseActivity is a separate class

Comment: Both the activites are in the Androidmanifest.xml, Apart from the DatabaseHelper... (The MainActivity and DatabaseActivity both are)

Comment: Can you post the activity_main.xml contents?

Comment: Yes, ill post it in the main question as chars too long for comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stacktrace has the "caused by" exception below the `RuntimeException` wrapper you have posted with specific details.

Anyway, one certain way your code can cause an NPE is that `buttonviewall` is not initialized before you're calling `ViewAll()` which calls a method on `buttonviewall`.

---

After edited question:

Remove the

```
}
{
```

The first `}` ends the `onCreate()` method and the second `{` starts a new initializer block that is executed at instance initialization phase. You need to execute that code as part of `onCreate()` as `<init>` is too early for e.g. `findViewById()`.

Comment: I See, Ive posted in the Caused by in the main question as its too big for the comment section, Ive moved the ViewAll() under the line of buttonviewall, bu still with the same error!

Comment: It should be? Ive copy and pasted the whole error message in the question. thanks for your help

Comment: Its linked to content_main.xml (Which i was informed is basically the same thing just the layout for it)

Comment: OKAY!!!! It seems to of worked from just removing those from the code!
I cant believe it was just an little error like that, which in turn caused all of this. Thanks for your continued support

Answer (score 1):

You have a NullPointerException at lines: 2184, 2233, 135, 1196, 102. Can you comment those lines under this answer. So I can take a look at them and see what is going on.

Comment: Im not 100% Sure how to access these lines, working on finding them

Comment: When you run the program and the error appears, click on the red number 2184 at at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)

Comment: They arent clickable, some of the lines are clickable, but those numbers are not